# How can I create symlink on Windows to remote Linux folder using SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, windows-10, symlink, mklink

I want to create a link to remote Linux folder from Windows 10 machine. I see Windows has SFTP and SCP commands built in for accessing remote machines. So there must be some way to create links as well.

I wonder if we can we do something like below? (forgive the syntax)

`mklink /D c:\remotelinks\remoteDir ssh:user@host//linuxdir`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight link like you mention maybe not, but you have some options:

https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp/releases/tag/v1.2POST1
https://medium.com/@danielmarinomirallestaset/mounting-linux-fs-in-windows-10-using-sshfs-e29c7ca81c87
http://makerlab.cs.hku.hk/index.php/en/mapping-network-drive-over-ssh-in-windows

After setting up something like you might be able to create links or shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem for now.
For others' information, yes, it is possible to create symlinks after mapping the remote using mentioned method. I wish it was possible to directly create link without the need to map the drive, since it limits how many we can map; but there are ~20 letters so shouldn't be issue most of time